# GAE Howto get Date from form Request

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a form where the user can select a date. I would like to store that as a date time.

```
# Throws error 'duedate must be datetime'
goal.duedate = self.request.get('duedate')
```

Obviously this doens't work because the form field is a string. What is the best way to convert form fields that are dates into GAE datetime objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `datetime` class's [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function.

For example, if your form submits the date like `'2011-02-15'` then you could do this:

```
import datetime
str_due_date = self.request.get('duedate')
goal.duedate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_due_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `strptime()` method of the [datetime.datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) class, passing in a format string that matches your date's formatting.